# Devise Confirmable Allows Signin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Devise is good but I can't get it to work properly on an app that's 100% complete. I found no sources that helped me. Is there any complete source for info on this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try and roll your own SessionsController (which could be overriding the devise [one](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb)).
Delete your SessionsController.

Then devise should "just work" (and respect the following config line):

```
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 0.days
```

.

For each controller which you wish to restrict access (to only signed_in users) you can add:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => []
```

*(where the except list could include some methods for which non-signed-in may access).*

Comment: Thanks Andy. I tried but that just made a routing error. Here's my routes.rb file: 

udityApp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  
  root to: 'static_pages#welcome'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'

Please tell me how to edit this file.

Comment: definitely delete this bit: `match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'`. Devise gives its own urls based on the root_path (with devise_for :users), so you don't need to add them.

Comment: It still doesn't work. That needs to be replaced by something or it breaks. The 'routes' file seems to be missing something to connect it to devise 'sessions' actions. 

routes.rb
AudityApp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users do

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
end
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  
  root to: 'static_pages#welcome'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'

Comment: There's seems to be something missing is routes.rb to enable the devise 'sessions' links. I have devise_for :users....but nothing for sessions. What's missing?

Comment: You've still got a reference to sessions#new (which doesn't exist if you've deleted it). also the signup is created by devise, so you don't need to add it. the rest looks ok.

Comment: Those are for the nav links so I can't delete them Andy. Somethings not connecting with devise but I can't find it. All works well except preventing signups from signing in before confirming. There's a disconnect somewhere. Where must it be?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling the users controller directly, devise has it's own urls (which you can modify) see eg [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes)

Comment: Thanks Andy. I used the last example on this page but I get this error on sign in 'No route matches [POST] "/sessions/user"'. Also the sign up doen't work now. I tried every example on this page also but no go.

Comment: You can see on that page it always calls devise/sessions#whatever, and not sessions/user or users#new etc.... make sense?

Comment: Yes it does Andy but still it doesn't work. Do I need devise Authenticatable or something?